# grep a word from a list of file as a result of grep before

Tags: linux, grep, cat

I have a command to grep a file with fullpath that contain a "TypeId: 0", here is the command

`grep -rnw /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv -e "TypeId: 0" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`

and here is the result:
`/home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv/521/1673332792072/segmentconfig.yaml /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv/521/1673333077920/segmentconfig.yaml /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv/521/1673333077920/segmentconfig.yaml.old /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv/515/1672993850766/segmentconfig.yaml /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv/515/1672993850766/segmentconfig.yaml.old /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv/703/1672987004847/segmentconfig.yaml /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv/703/1672987004847/segmentconfig.yaml.old`

Now I confuse how to `grep "numofvertice"` from each file from that list.
Anyone have an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```bash
grep -rnw /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv -e "TypeId: 0" | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'|xargs -I{} grep "numofvertice" {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this (GNU `grep`):

```
<STDIN> | grep -oP '\b\S+\.yaml' | xargs cat
```

Or with [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/):

```
cd /home/username/app/data/store/0/part/.mv
ack -wl  -e "TypeId: 0" | xargs cat
```

From `ack --help`:

> -l, --files-with-matches
> Only print filenames containing matches